# How to use Google Apps Script's LockService, with Sheets API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

i'm actually using google sheet api in automation to write cells etc.. It is working fine but issue is when we use concurrent run. When we write exactly at the same time, which can happen, both run try to write in the same cell and then there is a blank line and we lose one run.
I found out this LockService but it is in Google Apps Script, can we call that with Google Sheets API in Java code ?

Thank you

Comment: In that case, I think that there are 2 patterns. 1. Implement directly the function for avoiding your issue at the client side. 2. Use Web Apps as the wrapper API. In this case, the values can be put to Spreadsheet with the LockService of Google Apps Script. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) If these were not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike-san, for solution 1 can we implement directly this lockservice function into a java code instead of using google apps ?

Comment: @coq0rc You can't access Apps Script services outside of the Apps Script environment. Although try looking into the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api) perhaps you may be able to use it for your solution.